# Linuxでビルドしてインストールしたrubyに関するファイルをすべて削除するには

Tags: ruby, linux

Linux環境でrubyをビルドして `/usr/local` 以下にインストールしました。
その後 [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) でrubyをインストールしたため `/usr/local/bin` にあるrubyが不要になりました。

また、gemをインストールしたときに `/usr/local/bin` に置かれたコマンドも削除したいです。
`/usr/local` 以下のrubyに関するファイルをすべて削除する方法はありますか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

アーカイブを展開してmakeした後のディレクトリに".installed.list"という名前のファイルがあると思うので、探してください。その中に、インストールされたファイルのリストが記録されています。各種記録されているファイルの場所が/usr/local下であれば、.install.listに書かれたファイルを消していけば、ご希望のお掃除ができると思います。注意点としては、ディレクトリは消さずに、ファイルのみ削除してください。

gemについては、gemsディレクトリ丸ごとと、gemコマンドを消せば良いと思います。

上記作業によって消してはいけないファイルを消してしまうかも知れないので、削除行為はくれぐれもご注意を・・・（消さずに一旦 ~/tmp とかに移動させてしばらく様子見る、とかがオススメです）。

Comment: gemコマンドは消せばよいのですが、例えばpryをインストールしたときに作られる /usr/bin/local/pry などをどのように消す方法があるかについて知りたいです。

Comment: なるほど、そうすると、gemsディレクトリを一気に消す前に、gem listでインストールされているものをリストアップして、それらをuninstallしていった後に、gemsディレクトリを消すと良いかも知れません。それぞれuninstallしていくことで、/usr/local/bin下に配置されたものも消されると思いますので。

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflowに、"[How to uninstall Ruby from /usr/local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591501/how-to-uninstall-ruby-from-usr-local)" というタイトルで同じような質問がされてましたのでそれを参照するといいと思います。以下はその方法を日本語で書きました。

rubyがどこにあるか確認：

```
whereis ruby
```

rubyがある場所を教えてくれるのでrubyを削除：

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gem
rm -f /usr/bin/gem
```